# How action a button to open a new pane in java for a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, navigation, jbutton

I am creating a GUI in which my home page has a button labelled "Welcome to the Panel"

The point is that when you press on this button, it will navigate to a new page where I will have other functions. My only problem is that I dont know the syntax or how that when clicking a button, it will navigate to  new page.

Comment: *"My only problem is that I"* ..forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Welcome to the Panel");
btn.setActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Here you open the other window. You can use JFrame, JOptionPane or JDialog
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListner()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

     //code to show pane
    }

});
```

Comment: Ah thanks... im using netbeans. I had a clean pane where I drew a button. private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an `ActionListener` on your button and inside that action listener you make that panel (the page) visible.

How you do that depends on your layout, i.e. with a `CardLayout` you'd show the corresponding card (here's the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)). Using other layouts you might have to replace a component, e.g. if you use a `BorderLayout` and your content is placed in the center, replace the center component with the panel you want to show.

Note that if you're not familiar with layout managers yet, you should first have a look at those before doing dynamic changes to the ui (like navigation etc.).

Comment: Ah thanks... im using netbeans. I had a clean pane where I drew a button. 

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

                            

thats the code shown when the button was drawn. How from here, do I make that button when pressed open go to a new page where I can then add code onto that new page ?

Comment: @JasPn I already described that. You have to do that yourself since that depends on which layout manager you use.